# Print stars* in opposite direction with php

Tags: php, printf

Like This:

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

Not like this:

```
 *
 **
 ***
```

I mean in the opposite direction. Stars should increase in padding from the left. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Try some code yourself and then post it here if does not work.

Comment: A loop and alternatively `str_repeat()` function combined can give that result but `str_pad()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you think about this problem (since it's homework).

- How would you formalize what needs to be done? What does it mean when you have to right align something?
- Think of ways that could make right alignment more challenging - e.g. would you need to know the length of every line beforehand?
- What kind of [`string function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) would fit the bill?

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys . Trying to sort it out .

Answer (score 9):

Pad the strings to the required length using [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

Answer (score 3):

add

```
//&nbsp; for every desired space
```